# Minimum of two exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1 ~ \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2)$ be two independent exponentially distributed random variables.

Show that $\mathbb{P}\{\min(X_1, X_2) > t\} = \exp(-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t)$, and hence that $\min(X1, X2) \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$.

Comment: We want the probability that $X_1>t$ **and** $X_2>t$.  What is the probability that $X_1>t$?

Comment: Downvote: This is proven in the Wikipedia article about exponential distributions.

Comment: @user6312  So do I simply need to calculate X1>t and X2>t and then that will give me the answer if I multiply the two together?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus

I don't understand the Wikipedia article..  That is why I thought I'd ask for help....

Comment: @Cherizzle: Yes. By integrating, or by quoting your text, you find $\text{P}(X_1>t)=e^{-\lambda_1 t}$, and a similar expression for $\text{P}(X_2>t)$.  So $\text{P}(\min(X_1,X_2)>t=e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)t}$. So the cumulative distibution function of $\min(X_1,X_2)$ is $1$ minus the thing just computed. Differentiate to get the familiar exponential density function with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.  Or just recognize that the cumulative distribution function is familiar.

Comment: @user6312  Thanks for the help!  It all makes sense now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is instructive to make the following observation, giving intuition for the result.

Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively.
Let $X_i$, $i=1,2$, denote the waiting time until the first event to occur in the process $N_i$. Then $X_i \sim {\rm Exp}(\lambda_i)$, with $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent. Next, let $N = N_1 + N_2$. The process $N$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$. Finally, let $Z$ be the waiting time until the first event to occur in the process $N$. Thus, on the one hand, $Z \sim {\rm Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$, and on the other hand, $Z = \min \{X_1,X_2\}$. Hence, $\min \{X_1,X_2\} \sim {\rm Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$.

Comment: Note that this idea can be generalized to show that $\min \{ X_1 , \ldots ,X_n \} \sim {\rm Exp}(\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n)$, where $X_i$ are independent ${\rm Exp}(\lambda_i)$ variables.